# Does Yahoo Mail truly enforce the 1 TB limit? If so, what happened to users having more than 1 TB?

Tags: yahoo-mail

According to this [article](http://www.latimes.com/business/technology/la-fi-tn-yahoo-email-1-tb-storage-unlimited-20131008,0,5948465.story) (October 8, 2013), Yahoo is reducing the amount of free storage it gives users of its email service from "unlimited" to 1 terabyte:

> "We're moving to 1TB because 'unlimited' wasn't a feature that we
>   discussed very much or a feature that our users were that familiar
>   with," a Yahoo spokeswoman explained in a statement to The Times. "We
>   opted to move to 1TB instead, because we believe by having a huge
>   limit like 1TB it will inspire our users to store more in Yahoo Mail."

Does Yahoo Mail truly enforce the 1 TB limit? If so, what happened to users having more than 1 TB?

Comment: I'm guessing they truly do enforce it ... otherwise some hacker will try to put 1000TB there "just because". As you approach 1TB, you'll probably get some warnings, and then you probably won't be able to receive/send email until you delete some old messages.

Comment: Any idea what happened to users having more than 1 TB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo Mail truly enforces the 1 TB limit.